# Unable to mount a local directory into JupyterLab - podman ownership of mounted volumes is root

Tags: jupyter-lab, podman

I am trying to run the Data Science JupyterLab in Podman and I am having trouble with the volume's permissions once mounted. I would like to persist all my notebooks on external storage so I do not lose my work if the container is lost.

The container requires running as a specific user (jovyan), but the files when mounted are owned by root:root. The only way I can get it to work is if I make everything with permissions 777.

**ENVIRONMENT DETAILS:**

- Fedora35.
- SE Linux is DISABLED.
- The JupyterLab image is from DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook

The command I am using to launch the notebook is:

```
podman run -it -p 10000:8888 -v "${PWD}/lab-files":/home/jovyan/work docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:lab-3.3.0
```

The following snippet shows the different user/group settings for files that are mounted versus created from within the container.

```
[bryon@uni-dev ~]$ podman exec -it e68aeabbdad5 /bin/bash
(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~$ id
uid=1000(jovyan) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)

(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~$ cd work
(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~/work$
(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~/work$ touch aaa
(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~/work$ ls -las
total 3612
   4 drwxrwsrwx. 2 root   root     4096 Mar 16 09:14 .
   4 drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    4096 Mar 16 08:06 ..
   0 -rw-r--r--  1 jovyan root        0 Mar 16 09:14 aaa
3604 -rw-rw-rw-. 1 root   root  3689150 Mar 16 06:15 data1.csv
(base) jovyan@e68aeabbdad5:~/work$ exit
[bryon@uni-dev ~]$
```

Notice the file aaa. I set sgid on the host directory so all files created are in the group "bryon" (or root in the container).

The following snippet shows the file/directory info from the host:

```
[bryon@uni-dev lab-files]$ ls -las
total 3612
   4 drwxrwsrwx.  2 bryon  bryon    4096 Mar 16 20:14 .
   4 drwx------. 17 bryon  bryon    4096 Mar 16 18:57 ..
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 100999 bryon       0 Mar 16 20:14 aaa
3604 -rw-rw-rw-.  1 bryon  bryon 3689150 Mar 16 17:15 data1.csv
[bryon@uni-dev lab-files]$
```

However, if I create a file from the Jupyter container and then edit it on the host the permissions are changed to root:root and I can no longer access it in Jupyter

Even trying to write this down is starting to get complex...

How should I set up Juypter with Podman so I can manage the file ownership and groups in a way that lets them be edited from outside the container and inside the container?

Comment: You could use the __--uidmap__ and __--gidmap__ options. See https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem  and  https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#33-container-creates-a-file-that-is-not-owned-by-the-users-regular-uid

Comment: It is a common secure issue, which not related with jupyter.  (qemu is used to map your home folder into vm/podman machine, which is later mapped to container), let me practice and try to give some suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Update 2022-09-11 : --keep-id now supports specifying the container UID and container GID

Podman now supports specifying the container UID and GID as options when using **--keep-id**. The functionality is currently not  available in any released Podman version (only the main GitHub branch). See the PR
https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/15389

It should now be possible to specify **--keep-id** with options for UID and GID, instead of using **--uidmap** and **--gidmap**.  It is easier to specify the mapping by using **--keep-id**. (The command-line will be shorter).

#### Old answer (that is still relevant)

With **--uidmap** and **--gidmap** it is possible to create a mapping from your regular user on the host to the *jupyter* user and the *users* group in the container. Files created in the container by *jupyter:users* will be owned by your regular user on the host.

Here is a demo on a Fedora 35 computer with SELinux enabled:

In a Bash shell run these commands

```
mkdir lab-files
podman pull -q docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:lab-3.3.0
uid=1000
gid=100
subuidSize=$(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.UIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 ))
subgidSize=$(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.GIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 ))
podman --log-level=debug run --rm --name test -it -p 10000:8888 \
   -v "${PWD}/lab-files":/home/jovyan/work:Z --user $uid:$gid \
   --uidmap $uid:0:1 --uidmap 0:1:$uid --uidmap $(($uid+1)):$(($uid+1)):$(($subuidSize-$uid)) \
   --gidmap $gid:0:1 --gidmap 0:1:$gid --gidmap $(($gid+1)):$(($gid+1)):$(($subgidSize-$gid)) \
   docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:lab-3.3.0
```

(In the command above the option `--user $uid:$gid` is used. Some containers want to start running as root and then change to be running as another UID. If that would be the case, use `--user 0:0`).

In another Bash shell

```
$ podman exec -ti test sh
(base) jovyan@9f214321a3af:~$ id
uid=1000(jovyan) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
(base) jovyan@4fdb1502837d:~$ ls -ld .
drwxrwxr-x. 1 jovyan users 50 Apr  4 17:38 .
(base) jovyan@4fdb1502837d:~$ ls -ld work
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jovyan users 6 Apr  4 17:27 work
(base) jovyan@4fdb1502837d:~$ echo hello > work/file.txt
(base) jovyan@4fdb1502837d:~$ ls -l work/file.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 jovyan users 6 Apr  4 17:39 work/file.txt
(base) jovyan@4fdb1502837d:~$ exit
exit
$ id
uid=1006(erik) gid=1006(erik) groups=1006(erik) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ ls -l lab-files/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 erik erik 6 Apr  4 20:39 file.txt
$
```

I wrote a troubleshooting tip about this in the Podman GitHub repository:
https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem

Comment: I created a PR https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/pull/1677 to improve the official Jupyter documentation.

Comment: The :Z turned out to be the most important part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR it is a secure issue, if u don't care about it so much (own laptop), create jupyter image with root user.

Otherwise it will get things complicated (like what you want to share bi-direction)

podmad uses qemu in backend, so your host folder is mapped into VM (podman machine) first during `podman machine init -v /Users:/mnt/Users`, later it is mapped into container.

`root` permission is set for the mapping which is your user permission inside host

Ref: https://www.tutorialworks.com/podman-rootless-volumes/